# Comparing data between two sheets in Powershell - how to find data after cells with specific values?

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, automation

To start, unfortunately I cannot use Import-Excel (yet! organization is looking to implement the module "soon") or other outside modules, so am just working with excel objects manually.

I made an automated report that appends to an excel document every day. It looks something like the included picture. The servers and their data are not in the same cell position for each daily sheet, but are always grouped together (so Server1 and its data might be in the middle of today's sheet, but at the beginning yesterdays sheet). Databases can change, so I'll also be looking into error checking that a database actually exists on both sheets to compare them.

[image: Example Excel sheet]

I want to check the most recent sheet (sheet labeled 2020-08-10) and compare each database with the same databases on the oldest sheet (sheet labeled 2020-08-08) to get a size % difference between each database, but I can't seem to figure out how to automate finding the multiple "Database" rows of each server, then going down and grabbing each database and size to compare.

Any help or guidance to get me researching in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Scraping data back out of that spreadsheet format looks like it’d be a bit of a pain. Do you have the option of storing the raw data in another format alongside the workbook? E.g. a daily json / xml / csv file that you could read the data back from more easily?

Comment: @mclayton Actually that's a fantastic idea and would make my life so much easier. I unfortunately won't have json data from the past, but implementing that going forward should work just as well. Thanks a lot for pointing that out, no idea why I didn't think of that before, cheers. :)